# Connectivity in Android

Tags: android, networking, protocols, network-protocols

What is Integrated Digital Enhanced Network (iDEN) and Evolution-Data Optimized (EV-DO, EVDO) in Android Devices? What uses do that have and how do we implement them?

Comment: Welcome! Please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can help you with specific programming questions, not with finding literature.

Answer (score 0):

**Integrated digital enhanced network (iDEN)** is a mobile telecommunications technology from Motorola. Although mainly a cellular network technology, iDEN is best known for supporting cell phones with push-to-talk (PTT) capability that function as walkie-talkies. Although iDEN has some similarities with traditional PTT systems, it also offers many advantages.

http://www.techopedia.com/definition/7670/integrated-digital-enhanced-network-iden

What Is EV-DO?

EV-DO is a high-speed network protocol used for wireless data communications, primarily Internet access. EV-DO is considered a broadband technology like DSL or cable modem Internet services.

http://compnetworking.about.com/od/wirelessinternet/g/bldef_evdo.htm

Comment: thanks bro for reply.but please tell me about that how we use them in our app in android.any example or any application or anything else